# Grid Recycler View, children wrap_content

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with two columns and I want children views have height sized based on its content,
but by default children views are resized to the longest height of row. I have listview inside recycler view which is resized to height of its children.

```
                ItemAdapter adapter = (ItemAdapter) holder.mItemList.getAdapter();


                if(adapter == null){

                    adapter = new ItemAdapter(mItems.get(position));
                    holder.mItemList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else
                    adapter.setItems(mItems.get(position));

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.mItemList.invalidateViews();

                setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(holder.mItemList);
```

Is there any easy way to make views fits or I have to create my own two column layout, similar to [collection view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) in iOS ?

Comment: Actually I also faced the same problem. May I will be able to help you. Can you post your adapter class?

Comment: Could you describe your solution ?

Comment: please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I wanted view two images in two columns with the same size i did it using below code.

```
// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView 
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            int colSpan = 2;
            imgViewIcon.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / colSpan);
            imgViewIcon.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / colSpan);

        }
    }
```

Instead of imgViewIcon you can put itemLayoutView and then set the layoutParams(width and height).